# Is it possible to support several different versions of the same web service with a .NET web service client?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, wsdl

I have a case where I have a web service client as a part of a larger offering. The roles here are a bit reversed: the clients are the ones hosting the web services, and our application is the one consuming them.

The clients are currently all running one version of these web services (also initially built by us). With this new offering, the web service stack we offer will be expanded with a new functionality; clients can install this new stack if they wish to gain access to the new features.

However - a key requirement is backwards compatibility. (Possibly important FYI - we have one central installation of our web software piece running on our own servers; all of our clients use our system via the web **from our servers** only. The clients' systems, on the other hand, are hosted by them individually - and they all have their own installations of the products we integrate with (and install our web services as an add-on) to these products). As such - this new version of the project should ideally detect WHICH of the two versions of the web service stack the given client is using (given the URL to the WSDL and any other relevant info) - and use the appropriate web service client for communication. The URL, ideally, should be identical (i.e. "www.exampleCompany22.com/MyCompanyWebService/" can be running version 1, and "www.exampleCompany88.com/MyCompanyWebService/" can be running version 2). We should be able to detect which version they are using and use the appropriate code against it.

We have control over our system and over version 2 (the future, second version of the web services), but NOT the existing version 1 (which the clients already have installed and will have the option not to upgrade if they choose).

Is there any built-in functionality (or any library, or any other straightforward way) to implement this in .NET without any workarounds?

I don't think this is something that should be too difficult, but this probably isn't too
common a case... And definitely not something I've come across.

I can think of several ways to tackle the issue at hand already, but I would like to know if there is an actual "proper" way to do it (or if someone had a similar case before and can offer feedback on how they implemented it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways you can solve this, some of which depend on how exactly your web services work.

One way is that part of the install on the clients end is a call to your servers to notify them which version they have in use.  Before you make a call to the client, you would check an internal table to identify the version number and then take the appropriate actions.

A second way is to add a version number to each service file you install on the clients site.  For example: `OurService20.asmx` or `OurService30.asmx`.  Along with this you would have a standard service file called `GetVersion.asmx` which returned the latest version installed that you could use.

Another is to dump WSDL and ASMX services altogether and move to a RESTful architecture in which you keep the exact same naming scheme ie: `OurService.ashx`.  *Notice the difference in extensions*.   Using this method you could do an http GET such as `http://remoteclient/OurService.ashx?getVersion` and parse the response.  From then on you would know exactly what version they had installed.

Personally, I like the RESTful route as it gives you a lot more flexibility as well as opens your app up to be more easily consumed by other applications.

Comment: Keeping this info in a database is actually not a bad idea... However, it probably cannot be implemented in our case. The full background is that our clients are using a Java enterprise application which they install and host themselves; we provide an add-on for this application (with web services written in Java) that clients can install so that our system can communicate with theirs; for this reason, it doesnt't need to be open (it can only communicate with our system). The problem with the versions is that my whole reason for taking this route is the fact that I want to leave the clients

Comment: an option NOT to upgrade and keep their set-up the way it is. Our system should call our "add-on" on their end, detect which version they are using, and work with both...
But I really appreciate your answer; it was very useful and got me thinking.